# How does the sequence number work in the getChangedPackages API?

Tags: android

Since Oreo, a new method was introduced to make up for preventing apps from receiving the `PACKAGE_ADDED` implicit intent: [getChangedPackages](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getChangedPackages(int)).

However, the documentation isn't really clear regarding what the expected argument (`sequenceNumber`) really is. From what I could gather, the return value of `getChangedPackages` is a `ChangedPackages` object which exposes a [getSequenceNumber](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ChangedPackages.html#getSequenceNumber()) method. In addition, that sequence number is supposed to be reset to 0 every time the device boots.

This is how I *think* the function is supposed to be used:

1. Listen for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent and store 0 in a preference as the current sequence number.
2. Every time `getChangedPackages` is called, update the current known sequence number with the result's `getSequenceNumber` method.
3. Rinse and repeat.

I assume this will work, but it seems quite clunky to have to detect boot and set up a preference only to get an API to work reliably. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: You may need to persist the sequence number for your scenario. For apps that only need to detect changed packages while their process is running, that would not be necessary. But, yes, I agree that this is a goofy API. Had that been `getLastChangedTimestamp()` or something, it would have simplified scenarios like yours.

Comment: You're on top of the logic that can be implemented in the addressed scenario as there is no other option to date as @CommonsWare mentioned. Those who are coming across, go ahead and do the same.